# What is the correct JSON format for adding Resource Based policy to AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an existing Lambda Function Lambda1 , which has a resource policy attached. This resource policy provides access to the Lambda Function to AWS API Gateway and specifically to the resource API Authorizer.  If I view the resource policy on the Lambda Function console, I see the following JSON text

```json
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Id": "default",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "333380d7-2251-452f-8640-d919e5d3d1bf",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:492572502211:function:Lambda1",
          "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
              "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:492572502211:kkwykrocn2/authorizers/98sqsv"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want attach a similar `Resource based policy` to my another Lambda function Lambda2. I want to execute the following command

```sh
aws lambda add-permission --cli-input-json file://C:\script\policy.json
```

If I paste the JSON text into the policy.json file and execute the above command then I get the following error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "FunctionName"
Missing required parameter in input: "StatementId"
Unknown parameter in input: "Version", must be one of: FunctionName, StatementId, Action, Principal, SourceArn, SourceAccount, EventSourceToken, Qualifier, RevisionId
Unknown parameter in input: "Id", must be one of: FunctionName, StatementId, Action, Principal, SourceArn, SourceAccount, EventSourceToken, Qualifier, RevisionId
Unknown parameter in input: "Sid", must be one of: FunctionName, StatementId, Action, Principal, SourceArn, SourceAccount, EventSourceToken, Qualifier, RevisionId
Unknown parameter in input: "Effect", must be one of: FunctionName, StatementId, Action, Principal, SourceArn, SourceAccount, EventSourceToken, Qualifier, RevisionId
Unknown parameter in input: "Resource", must be one of: FunctionName, StatementId, Action, Principal, SourceArn, SourceAccount, EventSourceToken, Qualifier, RevisionId
Unknown parameter in input: "Condition", must be one of: FunctionName, StatementId, Action, Principal, SourceArn, SourceAccount, EventSourceToken, Qualifier, RevisionId
Invalid type for parameter Principal, value: {'Service': 'apigateway.amazonaws.com'}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

On checking the documentation of [add-permission AWS CLI command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/add-permission.html#examples) at  I found out using the `--generate-cli-skeleton` option that the correct format should be as below:

```json
    {                           
        "StatementId": "",      
        "Action": "",           
        "Principal": "",        
        "SourceArn": "",        
        "SourceAccount": "",    
        "EventSourceToken": "", 
        "Qualifier": "",        
        "RevisionId": ""        
    }
```

In the above JSON structure, there is no condition element, through which I could provide access to only the authorizer resource in the API Gateway. Could someone help me understand how to add the condition element of the above JSON structure?(Please see the JSON text pasted at the beginning of this question to see the condition element)

Answer (score 0):

The condition is going to be created **automatically** if you specify `SourceArn` and/or `SourceAccount`.

You can't create other conditions that those. You can chech [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) for creating permissions with these parameters, e.g.:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name my-function --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id sns-my-topic \
--principal sns.amazonaws.com --source-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:my-topic
```

Comment: @KurioZ7 How did it go? Did you set the source arn and got your condition created automatically?